# Sort next 5 lines along with sorting of a matched column in a text file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, grep

I am new to unix and formatting of text file through unix.
I have long pattern of fortran code in a file which is generated compile time

```
CASE('a')
 IF(use.eq.1)
  do something1
 ELSE
   do something2
CASE('e')
 IF(use.eq.1)
  do something3
 ELSE
   do something4
CASE ...
.
.
. So on
```

I have like 200 cases in one switch statement.
Some of the cases variable is repeated and are unordered, like they are not placed one after the other.

I want to sort the all these cases alphabetically.So that repeated cases can be grouped together and merged as one case.

Can anyone help me out please....

Comment: See [ask] then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:- Is that you are looking for ?.

```
> cat case.txt
CASE('a')
 IF(use.eq.1)
  do something1
 ELSE
   do something2
CASE('e')
 IF(use.eq.1)
  do something3
 ELSE
   do something4
CASE('c')
 IF(use.eq.1)
  do something1
 ELSE
   do something2
CASE('x')
 IF(use.eq.1)
  do something3
 ELSE
   do something4
CASE('a')
 IF(use.eq.12)
  do something1
 ELSE
   do something2
CASE('e')
 IF(use.eq.13)
  do something3
 ELSE
   do something4
>  perl -ne ' if($.%5!=0) { chomp; print } else { print "\n" } ' case.txt| sort -t\' -k2
CASE('a') IF(use.eq.12)  do something1 ELSE
CASE('a') IF(use.eq.1)  do something1 ELSE
CASE('c') IF(use.eq.1)  do something1 ELSE
CASE('e') IF(use.eq.13)  do something3 ELSE
CASE('e') IF(use.eq.1)  do something3 ELSE
CASE('x') IF(use.eq.1)  do something3 ELSE
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix only knows one standard tool for sorting, and that the command `sort`.  But, alas, it only sorts *lines*, not whole blocks.

So, what you might be able to do (but this is quite hacky, be warned) is this:

1. Convert all blocks into one-liners.
2. Sort the one-liners.
3. Convert all one-liners back to blocks.

Depending on how your blocks look like, this can be easy or tricky.  Please write a comment describing your block structure in more detail in case you think this way would be something for you, then I will extend my answer.

Comment: No, GNU awk does sorting too and it can sort whole blocks.